# How to install Microsoft Edge extension (addon) in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, microsoft-edge

There are ways to install Chrome extensions in Edge. But oppositely, how to install [Microsoft Edge-Store](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/) extensions in Chrome?

---

*There is one app available only in Edge-Store, which I want to use, but i'm not going to use any MS browser ever.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to load an extension from the Microsoft Edge-Store into Google Chrome successfully using the following steps.

1. Install the extension from the Edge-Store using the Microsoft Edge
   browser. Specifically, I used the [Microsoft Rewards extension](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/microsoft-rewards/bnplfnhcidhhdapmblniehfaaompjlck).
2. The url contains the extension ID, in this case
   `bnplfnhcidhhdapmblniehfaaompjlck`. Look for a folder with the
   extension ID in the following location:

   ```
   C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions
   ```
3. Copy the folder with the extension ID to somewhere else, lets say
   your Desktop. In the folder you copied, open the `manifest.json` file
   in a text editor.
4. In your editor, delete the lines with `"key":` and `"update_url":` and save the file.
5. Open Google Chrome, navigate to the extensions page `chrome://extensions` and check to enable Developer Mode.
6. Click Load unpacked and select the folder with the extension ID you copied earlier.

This worked for this specific extension with my specific setup. The extension activated immediately and could be pinned and interacted with.

Tested using:

- Microsoft Edge v88.0.705.81
- Google Chrome Canary v91.0.4434.0
- [Microsoft Rewards Edge Add-on](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/microsoft-rewards/bnplfnhcidhhdapmblniehfaaompjlck)

In Developer Mode you will be notified if there was an error with the extension or it simply would not load. This is useful if you try this with other extensions.

With browser extensions today being built using the WebExtensions API, extensions should for the most part be cross-browser compatible between Chrome, Edge, Opera and even Firefox [somewhat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Firefox_differentiators).

Comment: This worked! A couple of notes: 1. I needed to select the folder one down from the one with the extension ID. 2. It threw an error about a specific line of code after I did that, so I just deleted that line too. It worked perfectly after that. Thank you! The new tab page I like was Edge-only.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried installing MS Edge add-ons in Chrome, which is simply impossible. Microsoft will not give you the option to.